# Searching on an array of integers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-in

I've got a string coming in like so:

```
 '202,203,204,205,226,230,274'
```

I want to break this string down into an array of numbers and get back all the records with those Ids.

So far, I have:

```
string[] myArray = myString.Split(',');
int[] myIntArray = new int[myArray.Length];

 for(int x = 0; x < myArray.Length; x++) {
     myIntArray[x] = Convert.ToInt32(myArray[x].ToString());
 }

 model.Records = db.Records
     .Where(q => q.RecordId.Contains(myIntArray)
     .ToList();
```

It's complaining about Contains not working with ints.  Am I get confused as to what Contains actually does?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want to do:

```
.Where(q => myIntArray.Contains(q.RecorId))
```

The way you have it, you're expecting the `RecordId` to be an array (I'm assuming it's an `int`?), whereas I think you want to take the single `RecordId` and see if *it* is in the array of `int`s.